# Logo with text looks blurry, made in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

The logo i've created looks horrible on the screen.  The edges are blurry, far from crisp.  Here is some text in the logo

[image]

To me this looks far from professional.

I did this logo in Adobe Illustrator, the font is Ubuntu, size 32pt.  When saving for web, i've tried art optimized and type optimized.  The document is 72dpi.

A simple text logo and i can't get it crisp.  I've tried changing the anti-aliasing to crisp, sharp but it still looks like the picture above.  The background is white and the text is black.  How do i get my logo to look crisp?  Any design tips or processes when it comes to logo design, much appreciated.   This should be simple, black text on a white background but i'm scratching my head.

Comment: that looks fine to me. But if you want to tweak things, set the type in photoshop. Photoshop gives you more options for anti-aliasing.

Comment: also...any chance you're viewing this on a retina mac?

Comment: I also see no issues with the above image.

Comment: Looks decent to me, are you viewing it on a retina display? Or is your browser zoomed in? I made the mistake of thinking text was off a couple weeks ago without realizing my browser was at 120%

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Seems like You talking about subpixel displacement.
During rasterization application checks each pixel for opacity. If coverage above certain level - it's opaque, otherwise - transparent. Anti Aliasing just add semitransparency based on level of coverage.
In Your case - some lines lays between pixels, that cause booth of border pixels became semitransparent. To avoid that use 'pixel snapping', You can look for YT tutorials on that theme.

Well, that only needed while working with small scale.

p.s.: next time use PNG for sample image, JPG cause additional losses due compression.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. Anti-aliasing isn't necessarily transparent. It is if the background is transparent (possible in a PNG), but not if it's opaque (such as a JPG).